# Tweepy Error: Your credentials do not allow access to this resource

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I am using Tweepy to build a Telegram-based twitter client and when I try to post a tweet, I receive the following error message:

```
"TweepError occurred, args=([{'code': 220, 'message': 'Your credentials do not allow access to this resource.'}],)
```

I've managed to overcome this once, when I logged out and logged back in to my Twitter account (I'm using oauth with PIN verifier). But after some time posting stops working again and this error reoccurs.

How do I avoid this error with a single authentication?

I save access token and secret to a separate file and the application permissions are set to Write, Read, Access direct messages.